# SSRS Can you share subreport across multiple projects in a single solution

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

Having worked with SSRS for a few years I always wondered why there is no ability to share a report used as template/subreport across multiple projects. In my work situation we have not updated our technology for decades so I have no idea if later versions have added this feature, we have a 3 page policy document geared to the specific customer/period that needed to be an attachment at the end to both some of our Insurance and Quotation reports which we maintain in separate folders/projects and the template needed to be edited sometimes every 6 to 12 months and there was wording changes and sometimes removed/added information so it was pain to maintain in 2 projects.

After reading the following article:
Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/186deaf3-729f-4af6-9ea3-8ed40584fda2/can-subreports-be-from-subprojects-in-the-same-solution?forum=sqlreportingservices
no one had a perfect solution but having read it I had an epiphany how to solve it so this is more a suggestion that hopefully may help someone out, than an actual question in case someone knows better.

My solution I don't have to copy and paste as one suggestion was and only have to maintain one version however, still a case of actively deploying to multiple project folders on the SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

The method I use is:

- I keep my templates (reports used as sub-reports) in their own separate project with there own unique naming convention.
- I have employed 2 Configuration Deployment settings; one set to deploy to Insurance folder and one to Quotation.
- In my Insurance and Quotation projects respectively I have an empty report the same name as the template, same parameters. I actually do not even have to rename as I could also rename prior to deployment if I really wanted to in case I have to maintain a naming convention specific to the 2 project folders or if too troublesome to change the name if the report had already existed and used in multiple reports already I can move the template to the new templates project with no issues. You might argue copying and pasting and renaming would be faster in this case but at the downside of now having to have 3 identical reports in source control and not really much of a concern but I do have to actually remember to copy and paste my last change before I deployed to test server.
- At minimal I have put a water mark on the report so it is not completely blank so when I run it in Visual Studio it reminds me it is a place holder for a template rather than blank space/page on my report. Furthermore a small consolation in that it is faster to test since I don't have to wait for the template report to load.
- So when I deploy the actual template I am essentially overwriting the the individual Insurance and Quotation project folders blank version, although I don't actually need to deploy, first time it will add it then from every subsequent change will overwrite.
- The only issue I have encountered thus far but this is the same problem whatever method you use is if my template has its own header and footer, margins sometimes they all have to be in sync to the main report in order to avoid the nuisances of empty space and subsequent blank pages. I have to first copy/cut the logo or wording etc by convention I place everything in its own rectangle and paste to every Main report that needs it and thus use logic when to show or hide the respective header/footer by setting InitalPageName or PageName of other controls as appropriate and thus remove the header and footer sections from the template but this part has fortunately being a once off redesign.